# How do you drain down an Azure MessageReceiver message-pump?

Tags: c#, concurrency, azureservicebus

I've got a `MessageReceiver` which is pumping messages from a queue:

```
var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

var receiver = factory.CreateMessageReceiver(queuePath);

receiver.OnMessageAsync(HandleBrokeredMessageAsync);
```

`HandleBrokeredMessageAsync` is my delegate which the receiver pumps messages into.

When I call `Close()` on the receiver, it will stop pumping further messages from the queue. In order to avoid potential race conditions, I want to be sure all pending processing has completed before returning control.

I have considered tracking each call to `HandleBrokeredMessageAsync` into a `ConcurrentBag<T>`, removing them from the bag when they complete. I'd use a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) to block the process until the drain-down is finished, but it's not clear when to call [`CompleteAdding()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx): I would call it after calling `Close()` but can there be a gap between calling `Close()` and a message being subsequently delivered to the handler?

```
receiver.Close();
pendingMessages.CompleteAdding(); 
// Can additional messages be pumped after this?
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the sample here as it uses a ManualResetEvent to co-ordinate the close of the Run() method and the Close operation. A similar approach may work where you check within message processing and stop there (not accept the next message for processing) and then call close when all those concurrent processors are done?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16739691/1078351