# QueueClient.OnMessage throws StackOverflowException during Worker Role Start up

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-queues

I am trying to deploy my first Azure worker role and I have been running into this error when Run() method is called during service start up.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module.

I've tried to remote debug my code and the error is thrown at this line. MyPublisher is similar to MyQueue but it wraps Topic instead of a Queue. Any idea why QueueClient.OnMessage would cause StackOverflow?

> Client.OnMessage(messageHandler, options);

Here is the partial code. My Apology if it is not formatted correctly (will try to format) or anything is missing in code.

```
public class MyQueue
{
    String QueueName;
    public QueueClient Client { get; protected set; }

    public MyQueue(String queueName)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Creating service Queue with name : {queueName} ");
        QueueName = queueName;
    }

    public void EstableshConnection(string connectionString = null)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Establishing connection with service Queue : {QueueName} ");
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        connectionString = connectionString ?? CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
        NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(QueueName))
            namespaceManager.CreateQueue(QueueName);

        Client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, QueueName);
    }

    public void Send(BrokeredMessage message)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Sending brokered message to queue : {QueueName} ");
        if (Client != null && !Client.IsClosed)
            Client.Send(message);
    }

    public void OnMessage(Action<BrokeredMessage> messageHandler)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"OnMessage handler: Queue Name : {QueueName} ");
        OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions();
        options.AutoComplete = true; // Indicates if the message-pump should call complete on messages after the callback has completed processing.
        options.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1; // Indicates the maximum number of concurrent calls to the callback the pump should initiate 
        options.ExceptionReceived += LogErrors; // Allows users to get notified of any errors encountered by the message pump

//=====================StackOverFlowException on Client.OnMessage======
        if (Client != null && !Client.IsClosed)
            Client.OnMessage(messageHandler, options);  //This is where I get StackOverflowException Error. 
    }

    private void LogErrors(object sender, ExceptionReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception != null)
            Trace.WriteLine("Queue client processing error: " + e.Exception.Message);
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"closing queue {QueueName}");
        Client.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is my workerrole implementation.

```
public class MyWorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    #region Variables
    ManualResetEvent CompletedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    MyQueue RequestQueue;           //for Request
    MyPublisher ResponseTopicClient;    //ReponseTopic to notify Subscriber when processing is completed

    Public MyWorkerRole()
    {
        RequestQueue = new MyQueue("JobRequestQueue");
        ResponseTopicClient = new MyPublisher("JobCompletedTopic");
    }


    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        try
        {
            RequestQueue.EstableshConnection();
            ResponseTopicClient.EstableshConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceWarning($"Trace: starting service failed. Error {ex.Message} ");
        }
        return base.OnStart();
    }

    public override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            RequestQueue.Disconnect();
            ResponseTopicClient.Disconnect();
            CompletedEvent.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceWarning($"Trace: stopping service failed with error. {ex.Message} ");
        }
        base.OnStop();
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Trace: Starting Message Processing");

            //var receivedMessage2 = RequestQueue.Client.Receive(new TimeSpan(hours: 0, minutes: 2, seconds: 0));
            RequestQueue.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Guid resultGuid = (Guid)receivedMessage.Properties["CorrelationGuid"];
                    Trace.TraceWarning($"Trace: processing message with GUID {resultGuid}");

                    var messageToSend = JobProcessor.ProcessRequest(receivedMessage);
                    if (messageToSend == null)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceError("Trace: > Broken message!");
                        receivedMessage.Abandon();
                        return;
                    }
                    ResponseTopicClient.Send(messageToSend);
                    receivedMessage.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Trace.TraceError("Trace: Processing exception: " + ex.Message + "\nStack Trace" + ex.StackTrace);
                    Logger.Error("Processing exception: " + ex.Message + "\nStack Trace" + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            });
            CompletedEvent.WaitOne();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Trace: Run exception: " + ex.Message + "\nStack Trace" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            CompletedEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand recursion but I am calling Client.OnMessage only once. Isn't OnMessage just registers the action take when actual message is received in Queue? Also, the diagnostics data does not indicate that the Action delegate is called. Nothing is sent to queue yet as I'll be sending request from separate application. I can try to remove Topic from code and see if that resolves the issue but I want to understand how that can affect Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. So, the issue was not with the code. Following error was reported in WADWindowsEventLogsTable under my storage account.

> Faulting application name: WaWorkerHost.exe, version: 2.7.1198.768, time stamp: 0x57159090
>   Faulting module name: Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Profiler.SC.dll, version: 15.0.27128.1, time stamp: 0x5a1e2eb9
>   Exception code: 0xc00000fd
>   Fault offset: 0x000000000008ae7b
>   Faulting process id: 0xcf4
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d3b75ed89dc2f9
>   Faulting application path: F:\base\x64\WaWorkerHost.exe
>   Faulting module path: F:\plugins\IntelliTrace\Runtime\x64\Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Profiler.SC.dll

This gave me a hint about disabling the IntelliTrace and it worked just fine. Here is how you can disable while publishing a package through VS 2017.

> 1.) Right click on your worker role project and select publish from menu 
>    2.) In Settings page->Advanced Settings, uncheck "Enable IntelliTrace" option.

Answer (score 1):

When your worker starts, it calls the `Run` method and in your code, you have :

```
 //var receivedMessage2 = RequestQueue.Client.Receive(new TimeSpan(hours: 0, minutes: 2, seconds: 0));
```

RequestQueue.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>

So, The code doesn't wait for a new message because the first line is commented and it calls the `OnMessage`  method which recursibly calls itself again and again till the `StackOverflowException` gets fired

In all cases, you need to change the implementation because `StackOverflowException` will happen anyway when a new message is received

Comment: Haitham Shaddad, thank you for replying. I tried to simplify my code to call QueueClient.Receive and that gave me same error. I have also tried using same code suggested by @Abhishek Lal in this link but that didn't help too.  <br/>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714917/using-queueclient-onmessage-in-an-azure-worker-role<br /> I think my problem is somewhere else.